# Python Pandas: How to compare values of cells and two columns and maybe using If...Else statement to create another column with new values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, cell

I'm trying and researching a lot how to do this, but I'm having trouble mixing pandas with if, else and/or get values by index and compare it with if, else and assign a column with codes/values.
Explanation: I have this table below, I want to compare the cells in the **ID** column, and if the value of the posterior cell is equal to the previous one **AND** if in the **COD** column the posterior cell is equal to the previous one, **THEN** Result column = "no", otherwise **"pass"** and if neither  then **"unknown"**

This is the formula in excel that I made: =IF(B3=B2,IF(C3=C2,"NO","PASS"),"UNKNOWN").

[image]

Below I have also posted some code attempts. I can even create two columns with the first test (from the ID column cells) and the second test (from the COD column cells), and return with Boolean results, but I can't get the If, Else to join it all together and generate the values I want in another column.
Would I appreciate it if someone could help me?

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['ID'])
df['matchesID'] = df['ID'].shift(1) == df['ID']
df['matchesCod']= df['Cod'].shift(1) == df['Cod']
```

or

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['ID'])
test = (df['SWENo'].shift(1) == df['SWENo']) & (df['Cod'].shift(1) == df['Cod'])
```

I was trying something like this below

```
if df['ID'].shift(1) == df['ID'] and df['Cod'].shift(1) == df['Cod']:
    listProg.append('not')
elif df['ID'].shift(1) == df['ID'] and df['Cod'].shift(1) != df['Cod']:
    listProg.append('pass')
else:
    listProg.append('Unknown')
```

But the result is: "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()".

If you can help me I appreciate it, it can be with pandas or not or mixing. I just need it to work.  Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar approach in pandas will be to use `numpy.where` function.

With this code:

```
import numpy as np

df['Result'] = np.where(df['ID'] == df['ID'].shift(), np.where(df['Cod'] == df['Cod'].shift(), 'NO', 'PASS'), 'UNKNOWN')
```

I get below results:

```
   ID  Cod   Result
0   1    1  UNKNOWN
1   2    1  UNKNOWN
2   2    1       NO
3   3    1  UNKNOWN
4   4    1  UNKNOWN
5   4    2     PASS
6   4    2       NO
7   5    1  UNKNOWN
8   6    1  UNKNOWN
```

which seems more inline with your description of how Result value is derived.

Comment: Thank you very much @Pankaj Saini. This works perfect!
Could you give me a brief explanation of how this works, if possible?

Comment: Ya, so `numpy.where` works on arrays which has 3 arguments. First is the condition, when this evaluates to true, 2nd argument is invoked for each element and if the condition evaluates to false, 3rd argument is invoked.

Comment: Thank you @Pankaj Saini. It was very useful.  Have a nice day

Comment: @PankajSaini what to do if on finding equal values, set the value of column say `Cod` to *NO*

Comment: Well, you could do it in the next step using for example: df.loc[df['Result'] == 'NO', 'Cod'] = 'NO'